# videos for teaching and publishing in youtube

Tags: interactive-teaching

how to create videos for teaching maths and what are the Hardware and software required. I know to prepare slides but not free flow.I want to preapre videos just like teaching in a class room but without the teacher in the video.How to insert connecting arrows or how to highlight in the presentation

Comment: do what I do: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVGD3mU2diQ just use a camcorder and no post-production. Build a little wood frame to set over a desk. Cost about 100-250 depending on camera.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Speak up in your videos!

Comment: @Andrew sometimes kids gotta sleep.